# Push view controller, but go back to another one

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

Let's say that on my regular flow I have 
VC1 -> VC2 -> VC3 -> VC4

But I have a requirement that when I touch a special button on VC1 it needs to go to VC4.

No problem there. The problem is that when I tap the back button on VC4, it needs to go back to VC3 instead of VC1.

I already tried pushing From VC1 -> VC2 and VC2 -> VC3 without animation and then VC3 -> VC4 with animation, but you can see a quick glimpse of VC3 which looks awful.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why don't you just make the button a custom segue from V4 to V3?

Comment: @CaseyWest because the idea was to use the standard back button on the navigation bar. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think in this specific case, you can insert a view controller on the navigation controllers stack after presenting the 4th viewController

```
if let navigationController = navigationController {
  navigationController.pushViewController(vc4, animated: true)

  let vc3Index = navigationController.viewControllers.count - 1
  navigationController.viewControllers.insert(vc3, atIndex: vc3Index)
}
```

This should place VC3 next in line when the user presses back from VC4.  Untested code, btw.

Comment: Pffff dumb me. I was trying this same think but inserting BEFORE pushing, and I was seeing glitches. Didn't occur that I could do it AFTER

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the UINavCon's `viewControllers` to achieve the order you want.

```
func specialButtonInVc1() {
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(fourth, animated: true)
    self.navigationController?.viewControllers = [self, second, third,fourth]
}
```

Comment: This works, but is the same technique that @Derek mentioned 3 minutes before you. So I accepted his answer. I upvoted yours though! Thanks!